# ¿Por qué no puedo probar mi API desde localhost?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy tratando de conectar una API propia con un front mediante un endpoint, para hacer un registro de formulario, llamando a la función `createNewUser()`.

Mi endpoint está definido de esta manera y escucha el puerto 3000 (funciona bien desde Postman):

```
app.post('/signup', limiter, validarDatos, (req, res)=>{
    const{name, lastname, email, age, pass}= req.body;
    const newUser={
        name,
        lastname,
        email,
        age,
        pass
    };
    users.push(newUser);
    res.status(200).json(newUser);
})
```

Al correr la función recibo el siguiente error:

> POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/signup net::ERR_ABORTED 400 (Bad Request)

Esta es la función que estoy queriendo ejecutar para enviarle información desde el front. En este caso la variable `formData` está creada a modo de placeholder.

```
async function createNewUser(){

    let formData={
        "name": "franco",
        "lastname": "fernandez",
        "email": "fran@gmail.com",
        "age": "30"
    }
    
    await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3000/signup", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: formData,
        mode: 'no-cors'
    })
        .then(res=>{
            return res.json()
        })
    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias intentar con JSON.stringify(data), de este modo:

```
let formData={
    "name": "franco",
    "lastname": "fernandez",
    "email": "fran@gmail.com",
    "age": "30"
}

await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3000/signup", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    mode: 'no-cors'
})
    .then(res=>{
        return res.json()
    })
```

Comment: Gracias, había probado con JSON.stringify pero el resultado es el mismo, sigue apareciendo el "POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/signup net::ERR_ABORTED 400 (Bad Request)"